# URL or settings file to share IPSec VPN settings to iPhone

Tags: ios, vpn, settings

I have IPSec/L2TP server and I want to share connection settings via single URL or settings file to open and apply it in a single click on ios devices. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MDM solutions can help you craft a configuration profile so you can embed the XML file on a web server or share or vial email or other file delivery mechanism to iOS devices. Or you can roll your own file with any text editor and some research and trial and error.

- https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf

The above is very detailed and will take some time to digest, the end user steps are simpler:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/install-or-remove-configuration-profiles-iph6c493b19/ios